# Change custom attribute of AD users use PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Today I received a ticket requesting to change one of the custom attributes in Active Directory. My first issue is the number of users is too much, and I need to find out what value set those users. I tried to run the PowerShell script but could not find that attribute in the result.

Does anyone have any idea how to see the value of custom attribute?

[image]

Comment: You can find all users having the `extensionAttribute15` with simple ldap filter `(extensionAttribute15=*)` other than that your question is completely unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve that information by using :

```
 Get-AdUser -filter * -properties * | select SamAccountName,ExtensionAttribute15
```

since you say you're not seeing it in the result of your existing query I'd guess the bit you're missing is the -properties attribute, as without that it doesn't returned those additional attributes.

Once you have that output you can update the attribute using :

```
Set-AdUser -identity TargetUser -replace @{ExtensionAttribute15="newValue"}
```

or of course simply piping the output of your Get-AdUser query (including any filtering you've added to limit the scope of the result) to this without the -identity attribute.

Note, I use -replace because unlike -add it will both replace an existing value if one exists, or if the attribute isn't set it will add it.